# The correct realization of the adapter pattern in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, adapter

I need to create a data manager for my app without hardcoding on one file format, so if I would like to change the way of saving the data - I can do it easily. For this purposes I choose the Adapter Pattern.

I have the DataManager class where I wrote general methods for making data to store it.

```
@protocol DataManagerProtocol
@required
- (void) readFile;
- (void) saveFile;
@end

@interface DataManager : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *items;
    NSMutableString *destPath;
}

// many different methods

@end
```

Than I have a DataFileManager where there are method for storing data in one specific format:

```
@interface DataFileManager : NSObject
- (void) savePlist;
- (void) readPlist;
@end

@implementation DataFileManager

- (void) savePlist
{
    NSLog(@"The plist file was saved.");
}

-(void) readPlist
{
    NSLog(@"The plist file was readed.");
}

@end
```

And I have the DataAdapter to convert the interfaces:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DataFileManager.h"
#import "DataManager.h"

@interface DataAdapter : NSObject <DataManagerProtocol>
{
    @private DataFileManager *_dataFileManager;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) DataFileManager *dataFileManager;
- (id) initWithDataFileManager:(DataFileManager*) adaptee;
@end

@implementation DataAdapter

@synthesize dataFileManager = _dataFileManager;

- (id) initWithDataFileManager:(DataFileManager *) adaptee
{
    self = [super self];
    _dataFileManager = adaptee;
    return self;
}

- (void) saveFile
{
    [_dataFileManager savePlist];
}

- (void) readFile
{
    [_dataFileManager readPlist];
}

@end
```

So then in my DataManager file I write the method:

```
- (void) saveTheTestFile:(id)forAdapter
{
    [forAdapter saveFile];
}
```

and using it like this:

```
DataFileManager *dataFileManager = [[DataFileManager alloc] init];
DataAdapter *dataAdapter = [[DataAdapter alloc] initWithDataFileManager:dataFileManager];
[self saveTheTestFile:dataAdapter];
```

It works, but I believe something is wrong here - is there the way to make it more simple? I don't use ARC and need to release a lot of fileManagers - it's not so good, I believe. I totally confused in all this methods. Maybe someone can give a more interesting and simple realization of this pattern for my case? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a category on the DataManager class defined inside the implementation file of the DataFileManager class.

Here is an example how it should look like:

```
//class DataFileManager's implementation
@implementation DataManager (DataFileManager_Adapter)
// Methods to allow DataFileManager to connect to DataManager
// Methods that DataFileManager can use to calculate values dependent on both DataManager
//  and DataFileManager
@end

@implementation DataFileManager
// DataFileManager's methods
@end
```

The classical approach is to create a third intermediary class like what you have done but, in objective-c, categories eliminate that need.
[Adapter interfaces in Objective-C, using categories.](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/05/adapter-interfaces-in-objective-c-using.html)